# JavaScript как запретить переход на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, iframe

Разбираюсь в межоконных событиях. Выбрал для примера topface, хочу написать межоконную кликаклку или что-то такое.

Как запретить фрейму делать переход страницы, которая его загружает? И каким образом вообще topface может взаимодействовать и "понять", что он во фрейме? И почему в редакторе на данном сайте (stackoverflow) не происходит переход?

```js
  var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

  var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

  if (iframeDoc.readyState == 'complete') {
    iframeDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
  iframe.onload = function() {
    var iframeDoc2 = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDoc2.body.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    // iframeDoc2.body.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'Новый BODY!';

    var iBody = iframeDoc2.body;
      // iBody.innerHTML = 'Новый BODY!';

    var iId = iframeDoc2.getElementById('id');
      // iId.innerHTML = 'Новый ID!';

    var iBu = iframeDoc2.getElementById('button');
      // $( iBu ).trigger('click');
      while (true) {
        console.log("1");
      }
  }
```

```css
  *{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }
  iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<iframe src="http://topface.com/"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с этим материалом - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182993/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-going-back-forward-in-history-when-scrolling-horiz

Comment: Спасибо! Как window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { не задавать а сразу запретить? Пробовал ретурн фалс - ничего.

Comment: @VINET попрубуйте e.preventDefault()

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

  var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

  if (iframeDoc.readyState == 'complete') {
    iframeDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
  iframe.onload = function() {
    var iframeDoc2 = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDoc2.body.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    // iframeDoc2.body.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'Новый BODY!';

    var iBody = iframeDoc2.body;
      // iBody.innerHTML = 'Новый BODY!';

    var iId = iframeDoc2.getElementById('id');
      // iId.innerHTML = 'Новый ID!';

    var iBu = iframeDoc2.getElementById('button');
      // $( iBu ).trigger('click');
      while (true) {
        console.log("1");
      }
  }
```

```css
  *{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }
  iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<iframe src="http://zulubet.com/"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```